# How to unlock landscape mode with code on tap of UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, landscape

At the moment, my whole app is in portrait mode and is locked to that only. I want landscape enabled only when a button is tapped and then back to portrait when another button is tapped.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view .m file you should see a function towards the bottom:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
   } else {
       return YES;
   }
}
```

Change the appropriate orientation to make it proper and reference it in your button. Or copy and paste the if then in your button. That should do it.